# Keycloak as IdP with own implementation of Resource Server

Tags: keycloak

Is there a way of using Keycloak only to Authenticate user, but with own mapping to roles with Spring?

I would like to authenticate API Gateway in keycloak first, but then provide internal JWT Token with authorized roles inside my microservice world.

Answer (score 1):

In [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-oauth2-resource-servers), I do map Spring `authorities` from roles that Keycloak sets in JWTs. Is that what you are looking for?

If what you want is having a hand on access token claims, two cases:

- the claim is already in the token but with a different value than what you expect (missing roles, outdated email, ...). Then, it is very likely that Keycloak admin API exposes what you need to update users data. Check that a "confidential" client with required roles is declared with client-credentials flow enabled (or declare a new one) and have relevent resource-server call admin API for updates (with `WebClient`, `RestTemplate`, `@FeignClient` or whatever is capable of using client-credentials flow).
- the claim does not exist yet. Then, define a new Keycloak "mapper" to add a private claim. [Here is a sample](https://github.com/ch4mpy/user-proxies/tree/main/api/proxies-keycloak-mapper). You can have a look at [`security`](https://github.com/ch4mpy/user-proxies/tree/main/api/security/src/main/java/com/c4_soft/user_proxies/api/security) module to figure out how this new private claim is parsed (by [`ProxiesClaimSet`](https://github.com/ch4mpy/user-proxies/blob/main/api/security/src/main/java/com/c4_soft/user_proxies/api/security/ProxiesClaimSet.java)) into an `Authentication` [custom implementation](https://github.com/ch4mpy/user-proxies/blob/main/api/security/src/main/java/com/c4_soft/user_proxies/api/security/ProxiesAuthentication.java).

In any case, the authorization-server (Keycloak) is the only place to define claims, issue JWT and sign it. JWT validation by JWT decoder on resource-server involves much more than just checking expiration date: issuer, issued-at, token integrity (server signs the payload with a private key and exposes a public one to ensure the token content was not modified), and more are verified too.

You want to make access control inside resource-servers? Great! Ensure that authorization header with Bearer access-token is forwarded by the gateway from client(s) to resource-server(s) and configure your resource-server(s) as described in the article above.

#### P.S.

In the article you'll also find a way to test security rules (both unit and integration) with mocked authentication. This is what, in my opnion, makes resource-server(s) a better place to implement access-control: security rules are of primary business importance and fine grained unit-testing is essential.

Other note, if you go for additional private claim(s) with Keycloak mapper(s), pay attention to `pom.xml` file, `java/main/resources` and implemented interfaces of [`ProxiesMapper`](https://github.com/ch4mpy/user-proxies/blob/main/api/proxies-keycloak-mapper/src/main/java/com/c4_soft/user_proxies/api/keycloak/ProxiesMapper.java) into `proxies-keycloak-mapper` module.

Last, you should also follow the first 3 of [those tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) (for real: write the code and run the tests), it will take you less than an hour and will save you many more hours struggling with your resource-server(s) security implementation.

Comment: Great article, but no, I need to:
1. Authenticate user in keycloak
2. Create jwt token for other microservices containing user claims fetched from DB, validate it and check expiration time

Comment: See my developped answer